# show template in module magento 2

Tags: controllers, magento2.3

I am new at developing Magento 2 (Magento 2.3), I develop module to show my custom template But I get this error

when I **`die('sumthing')`** in **execute** function it works correctly

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Parcode\Contacts\Controller\Index\index\Interceptor

this my code

*route.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="contacts" frontName="contacts">
            <module name="Parcode_Contacts" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

my Controller: Index

```
<?php
namespace Parcode\Contacts\Controller\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_postFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        // die('somthing'); works correctly
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

layout file:

*view/layout/contacts_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Parcode\Contacts\Block\Contact" name="contacts_index_index" template="Parcode_Contacts::index_index.phtml"  />
        </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

template: 
*view/templates/index_index.phtml*

Comment: Would you include the other two files you referenced? Also, do you have a plugin somewhere? As a side note the template should be in your module's `view/frontend/templates/` and the layout: `view/frontend/layout/`.

Comment: can you share you layout coding?

Comment: @sourav yes of course

Comment: check my answer

Comment: if solve your problem please tick

Answer (score 0):

I have checked you are using wrong template path. Always use templates not template.

In magento 2 module templates are store in
Path: view/frontend/templates/